# Submit handler in hook_form_alter not working in d8

Tags: 8, forms

I have **hook_form_alter** as follows :

```
function auto_ga_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $base_url;     
    if($form_id == 'node_p_request_form' || $form_id == 'node_p_request_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_f_pro_request_form' ) { 
      $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit_fn';
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit_fn';
   }
}


function custom_form_submit_fn(&$form, $form_state) { 
  echo 'reached in submit handler';exit;
}
```

But its not going to the submit handler . both usage ( **`$form['#submit'][] OR  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]`**) of submit handlers not working

And idea ??

Comment: Have you checked this Url "https://www.drupal.org/node/2637958" ? Hope this will help you.

Comment: @PallaviSugandhi No luck , its not working even i tried with **mymodule_form_node_form_alter** , its going to the form_alter , but not to the submit handler , I think its the issue with button i specified , not sure though . Is there any way to find which button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing looks like it should work.

Doing an `echo` is undetecable in the submit handler, since Drupal will do a redirect after the POST request and thus clearing all of the output generated but Drupal in the actual submit handler.

A simple way to test if the submit handler is called or not is to insert a `die()`

Reasons for submit handler not being called could be:

- You submit the form with a button you haven't added a submit handler on and that already have one or more attached to it.
- Another alter hook removes your submit handler (unlikely)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 the parameters are changed

Please add following parameters in hook_form_alter and example_form_submit_handler:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)

example_form_submit_handler($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's doesn't change anything to specify the FormStateInterface in function signature